# Rename all file in a folder with .BAT code

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-rename, windows-scripting

thanks for your help in advice;
I'm new on bat scripting and i need to write a program that rename all file in a folder keeping the file extension without renaming file already renamed.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=C:\StockSys\PcHost\IF\"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%folder%" /b /a-d') do (
if /i not "%%a"=="%~nx0" (
set "extension=%%~xa"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ren "%folder%%%a" "!fullstamp!!extension!"
endlocal
)
)


EXIT /B
```

This is what i'v written so far, it is kinda working, but if i'v got multiple files with the same extension it dosen't rename all off them, it renames only 1 x extension >> i provide a screenshot
[image]

i would also like to avoid renaming files already renamed but this script.

Thanks.

Comment: You're renaming files to just <datetime>.<existing file extension>, so of course it won't work. The first .scw file gets renamed, but it cant rename the second .scw file it finds as that specific filename has already just been used. If you kept the original filename, but added the datetime string to the beginning or end of the file name then that should work.